# Laravel method Auth user redirect to login with message

Tags: php, laravel

I want redirect guest on login with message, but method:

```
Auth::user();
```

redirect on page login only without message. How I can add message?

Example:

```
redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Please auth!!');
```

Comment: You can write your own middleware. It's simple. P.S. It is not `Auth::user` who redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a middleware, that performs a redirect. Create the middleware at `app/Http/Middleware/Withmessage.php` and add it to `app/Http/Kernel.php` after `StartSession` string.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Withmessage::class, // <-- here
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

The code of a middleware contains only one string, that differs from a clean middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class Withmessage {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $route = $request->route()->getName();
        if(!Auth::user() and $route === 'button-click-button') {                
            return redirect()->route('login')->with('error', 'Please auth!!');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. And when I go to main page (if !Auth) I redirected to login page, why?

Comment: What page are you requesting when you get redirects?

Comment: I want do redirect with message when user want order item. When he press the button.

Answer (score 0):

return redirect('/login')->with('msg','Email or Password does not match');

Answer (score -1):

You can add to you controller this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

also you can only one method to check auth

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->only('nameOfMethod');
}
```